# oracle apex point to domain missing universal theme resources

Tags: dns, oracle-apex

I created an oracle cloud application and I bought a domain and I have followed the Dimitri blog for the installation process. works well at the final step I want the app to point the domain name but it ends up with this  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja6Q1.png] and I don't know how to fix this error could anyone help me to solve this problem. I used putty for ssh and here is the code

```
'''
server {
    server_name    comida.org.in www.comida.org.in;
    root           /usr/share/nginx/html/comida.org.in;
    index          index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.comida.org.in/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.comida.org.in/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

     location / {
    rewrite ^/$ /ords/f?p=104:1:0 permanent;
}
    location /ords/ {
    proxy_pass https://cet0g4zjcbpciit-db202006231759.adb.ap-hyderabad-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/;
    proxy_set_header Origin "" ;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    send_timeout                600;
  }

  location /i/ {
    proxy_pass https://cet0g4zjcbpciit-db202006231759.adb.ap-hyderabad-1.oraclecloudapps.com/i/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

}

server {
    if ($host = www.comida.org.in) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if($host = comida.org.in) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen         80;
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name    comida.org.in www.comida.org.in;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}'''
```

help me to fix this, please

Comment: For future reference, the blog post referred to is: https://dgielis.blogspot.com/2019/09/free-oracle-cloud-7-setup-web-server-on.html

Comment: I've had a look at your website and it looks like it is loading the universal theme resources fine. You might just need to do a full browser refresh. Some static images on the page aren't loading, I think the relative paths might be wrong.

Comment: do you know why this error occurs while sending mail. I have followed all the instructions as per dimitrihttps://dgielis.blogspot.com/2019/10/free-oracle-cloud-11-sending-emails.html .ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available

Comment: That's not related to this question, but anyway - have a read through the comments on that blog post, it seems a few people in some locations have encountered that problem.